# Getting extra unwanted whitespace in tailwindcss using in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, tailwind-css

I am trying to learn react js with tailwindcss but I am getting extra whitespace which is not detecting when I inspect it also in mobile view it occupies half of the screen

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Hero = () => {
  const [animated, setanimated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setanimated(true);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div
      className="min-h-screen w-screen flex justify-center items-center flex-col-reverse md:flex-row md:justify-around "
      style={{
        background: "linear-gradient(to bottom,  #aaacc0, #F0F4FD)",
      }}
    >
      <div
        className={`${
          animated ? "scale-y-100" : "scale-y-0"
        } mt-4 text-center font-nunito transform transition duration-1000 ease-in-out`}
      >
        <h1 className="font-bold text-3xl md:text-6xl md:flex-col">
          Fresh Delicious
      <span className="font-extrabold text-3xl md:text-6xl"> Noodles</span>
    </h1>

    <p className="text-base mt-5 ">We cook most tasty Noodles in Mumbai</p>
    <p className="text-base">
      We care for you! We maintain{" "}
      <span className="md:text-lg md:font-semibold"> Hygein</span> and{" "}
      <span className="md:text-lg md:font-semibold"> Contactless</span>{" "}
      delivery!
    </p>
    <button className="inline-block bg-yellow-400 px-10 py-5 rounded-full mt-10 shadow-lg border-2 text-lg font-semibold text-black uppercase tracking-wide duration-1000 animate-bounce">
      Order Now!
    </button>
  </div>
  <img
    src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/assets/bowl.svg"}
    alt="BOWL"
    className={`${
      animated ? "scale-90" : "translate-x-full translate-y-full"
    } mx-5 my-5 w-auto h-auto md:max-w-xl transform transition duration-1000 ease-in-out `}
  />
</div>
```

);
};

export default Hero;

you can see website here
[my website where I am getting bug](https://mayureshshitole.github.io/noodlesweb/)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a class on #root div tag

```
overflow-x-hidden
```

or

```
#root {
 @apply overflow-x-hidden; 
}
```

The reason this is happening are the animation's starting point.